# teradata odbc .jar file

Tags: jar, odbc, teradata

getting below error when trying to connect to Teradata Db. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver 
do I need to add teradata odbc .jar file? if yes then where can I find it?

Comment: You need to install the JDBC driver and make sure that your CLASSPATH is includes the location to JDBC driver. You used to be able to download it from the Developer Exchange. It appears that's not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to see these two jars from your java code:

```
* terajdbc4.jar
* tdgssconfig.jar
```

I believe odbc is no longer supported to bridge from jdbc, so you need to run a thin jdbc connection.